# Highest order element in $S_5$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

What is the largest order of an element 
in the group of permutations of 5 objects ?

Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: From Cauchy's Theorem we know that the answer is at least 5.

Comment: What are the elements? What structures do permutations have? Btw, the answer is $2\cdot3$.

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning behind the answer ?

Answer (score 7):

First of all: note that many elements have the same order (all 2-cycles, all 3-cycles, a 2-cycle and 3-cycle combined, etc...). You only need to check every "form" of element that is available. I recommend using the *disjoint cycle notation* for this.

The element you seek might be composed of multiple cycles, and a single $n$-cycle has order $n$. Out of those, the highest order is a $5$-cycle with order $5$.

So what is the highest order we can create by combining multiple cycles? The order of such combination will be the $\text{lcm}$ of the order of the subcycles. Also note that $1$-cycles don't do anything, so we only need to check combinations of cycles of length $\geq 2$.

1. $2$-cycle + $2$-cycle: order $\text{lcm}(2,2) = 2$.
2. $2$-cycle + $3$-cycle: order $\text{lcm}(2,3) = 6$.

Hence the answer is: any combination of a $2$-cycle and $3$-cycle, e.g. $(1 2)(3 4 5)$.